# Best way to generate Json-friendly result (.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I'm now using `ListItem()` for Json format result, but the generated Json text has an extra property called `"selected = false"`, I know this is used for drop down list, but I want my app runs faster so I don't want this property. Do you know any other way to get the similar result?

Here is my code:

```
List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>() {
    new ListItem() { Text = "Email", Value = "Pls enter your email" },
    new ListItem() { Text = "NameFull", Value = "Pls enter your full name" },
    new ListItem() { Text = "Sex", Value = "Pls choose your sex" }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your JSON serialiser you may or may not be able to tell the serialiser to ignore this property.

You'd be better off just creating a class that only has the fields you need. e.g.

```
public class MyListItem
{
    public string Text { get;set; }
    public string Value { get;set; }
}

List<MyListItem> list = new List<MyListItem>() {
    new MyListItem() { Text = "Email", Value = "Pls enter your email" },
    new MyListItem() { Text = "NameFull", Value = "Pls enter your full name" },
    new MyListItem() { Text = "Sex", Value = "Pls choose your sex" }
};
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I want! Thanks a ZILLION! ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC Beta you can serialize any object to JSON using Json function and anonymous types.

```
public JsonResult GetData() {
    var data = new { Text = "Email", Value = "Pls enter your email" }; 
    return Json(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ListItem` - use a custom type that has only the properties you want.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to, could you please show me an example?